# Riemann Sum Integration problem

Tags: calculus, summation

I do not understand how to start this problem. I know I have to integrate from 0 to 1 and that n=3 but thats all. Hints/clues appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Do you know what a Riemann sum is?

Comment: i know n=3, i am confused at what the integrand is myself.

Answer (score 1):

Hint - Check the different sums given in (a)-(e), and take into account that:

== The function *must* be evaluated in points of the given subintervals $\,[x_i,x_{i+1}]\subset [0,1]\,$ , and way more important:

== Every value of the function must be multiplied by the correspoding subinterval's length!

Comment: then only B would be the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, indeed (b). Can you explain why the $\,2\,$ before the first summand, though? Also observe that (c) *almost* makes it...what's the problem with it, though?